# Появление EditText

Tags: android

У меня есть `CheckBox` и поле `EditText`.
Хочу сделать так,чтобы при активном `CheckBox`(когда поставили галочку) появлялся сразу же `EditText`. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С точки зрения пользовательского опыта логичнее не совсем скрывать виджет, а делать его неактивным, чтобы пользователь знал, что существует поле ввода, которое он может разблокировать чекбоксом. Код, управляющий активностью поля ввода, в зависимости от состояния чекбокса (чекбокс отмечен - поле активно, не отмечен - не активно):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText editText;
    private CheckBox checkBox;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        editText.setEnabled(checkBox.isChecked());
        //editText.setVisibility(checkBox.isChecked()? View.VISIBLE: View.INVISIBLE);

        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                editText.setEnabled(isChecked);
                //editText.setVisibility(isChecked? View.VISIBLE: View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Если нужно сделать именно невидимым, тогда вместо строчек с `editText.setEnabled()` (их удалить) раскоментировать строки с `editText.setVisibility()` сразу за ними (устанавливает видимость в зависимости от состояния чекбокса)